# No bounce light in eevee?

Tags: lighting

I would like to know why there's no bounce light in Eevee?

I have a really simple setup with a spotlight and a nearby plane but nothing is bouncing onto it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No light bounce, it's the way Eevee works by default, in order to calculate faster. If you want to reintroduce light bounces, create a *Light Probe > Irrandiance Volume*, scale it, stretch it so that it contains all the area you want to be taken into account, in the *Object Data* panel give it a better *Resolution* if necessary, then in the *Properties panel > Render > Indirect Lighting*, press on the *Bake Indirect Lighting* button. You'll have to bake again if you make some changes in your lighting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks the reason I asked was because
I wanted to rotate within a room but rotating causes me to see the outside walls

So i wanted to hide the walls but still get the way the light is shaped by the holes in the wall (Light placed outside)
to cast onto the interior while i am working in Eevee

So far the moment I hide the geo, the light shape the holes in wall makes, will be gone too

Comment: maybe edit your question and try to explain more in detail (with images if possible)

Comment: ok just did it thanks for the help